# Remove multiple directories from URL with unknown variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to build a rewrite rule that would take a URL like this:

```
website.com/gallery/{WILDCARD}/gallery-name
```

and convert it to this:

```
website.com/gallery-name
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$\/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I found the answer after I posted my question:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: With a slight change to `RewriteRule ^/?gallery/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2 [L,R=301]` such rules work likewise in distributed and in central configuration files.

Comment: The first capturing group is redundant. Unless the "gallery-name" can literally be anything (including slashes and _nothing_ - which I doubt) then the regex should be made more restrictive to avoid unnecessary redirects. Is the `NC` flag really necessary here?